# How to define a function checking DNA substrings?

Tags: python, function, substring

I'm supposed to write a python 3 function  that takes three arguments - two DNA segment strings then a 3-base motif and returns True if both DNA segments contain the motif, and False otherwise.
I've written the function, however it returns True or False AND None... Why? 
Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

```
def common_motif(dna_seq1, dna_seq2, x):
    """This function returns True if both DNA segments contain the motif, and False otherwise"""
    count_1 = dna_seq1.count(x) 
    count_2 = dna_seq2.count(x)
    if count_1 > 0:
        if count_2 > 0:
            print(True)
    else:
        print(False)

print(common_motif("GATGCGCACGCG", "ATGGATTACCAT", "GAT"))
True 
None
```

Comment: You are printing the result of `common_motif` (the object returned by `common_motif`). Since the function doesn't explicitly return anything, it returns `None` by default. Therefore, you are printing `None`. You also print `True` or `False` as a side-effect of calling the function.

Answer (score 2):

It prints `True` or `False` as a [side-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)), and it *returns* `None`. In general, we'd like to write functions that don't have side effects (so-called 'pure' functions) and instead return all the things we need from them. (Except in debugging: we print things from within functions all the time when debugging.)

You probably want to do this:

```
def common_motif(dna_seq1, dna_seq2, x):
    """This function is stupid """
    count_1 = dna_seq1.count(x) 
    count_2 = dna_seq2.count(x)
    if count_1 > 0:
        if count_2 > 0:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Note that this might still return `None`, e.g. if `count_1 > 0` and `count_2 < 0`. Python functions that don't have an explicit `return` just return `None`.

Depending on the logic you want, you could cover this eventuality and simplify things a bit:

```
def common_motif(dna_seq1, dna_seq2, x):
    """This function is stupid """
    count_1 = dna_seq1.count(x) 
    count_2 = dna_seq2.count(x)
    return (count_1 > 0) and (count_2 > 0)
```

This returns `True` if those two conditions are met, and `False` otherwise.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you!

Comment: @lena np, don't forget to accept or upvote if it helped you :)